# Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t^2)}{1-t^2+t^4}\ln(t)dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t^2)}{1-t^2+t^4}\ln(t)dt=-\frac{4}{3}G  $$ G is Catalan's constant.

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t^2)^2}{(1+t^2)(1-t^2+t^4)}\ln(t)dt=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t^2)^2}{(1+t^6)}\ln(t)dt$$

Do series expansion:

$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1(1+2t^2+t^4)t^{6n}\ln(t)dt$$

Integrate term by term:

$$I=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left( \frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}+\frac{2}{(6n+3)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^2}  \right)$$

Re-organize them:

$$I=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left( \frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(6n+3)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^2}\right)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{3}{(6n+3)^2} $$

The first part is Catalan's constant:

$$I=-G-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{3}{(6n+3)^2}=-G-\frac{3}{9}G=-\frac{4}{3}G$$

Done.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\frac{1}{144} \left(-112 C-4 \sqrt{3} \pi ^2-\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)\right)$$ with the Catalan and PolyGamma functions.

Comment: but this is not the simplest form...

Comment: Ah, I think I know how to solve it now. Just list them and it is done!

Comment: So is it $-4G/3$ or $4G/3$? I think when you say "re-organize them" you dropped a $-$ sign.

Comment: oh, right, sorry about that, I have fixed it, thank you! @Gary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Addendum:** This is in response to the original question asked by the OP, which was essentially why the below is true:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left( \frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^2}\right)=\frac{10}{9}G$$

---

So the obvious way to split this up would be into the sums

$$\newcommand{\AA}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\BB}{\mathcal{B}}
\begin{align*}
\AA &:= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(6n+1)^2} = 1 - \frac 1{7^2} + \frac{1}{13^2} - \frac{1}{19^2} \cdots \\
\BB &:= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(6n+5)^2} = \frac{1}{5^2} -\frac{1}{11^2} + \frac{1}{17^2} \cdots
\end{align*}$$

Recall, by definition,

$$G := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{5^2} - \frac{1}{7^2} \cdots$$

Notice that

$$\AA + \BB = G - \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{9^2} - \frac{1}{15^2} + \frac{1}{21^2} \cdots$$

Multiply the bottom of each term in $G$'s summation by $-3^2$. Then

$$-\frac 1 9 G =  -\frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} \frac{1}{3^2} - \frac{1}{3^2} \frac{1}{5^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} \frac{1}{7^2} \cdots$$

This is, once you simplify, precisely the missing terms. You can also see this as

$$\AA + \BB = G + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(6n+3)^2}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(6n+3)^2}  
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3^2 (2n+1)^2} 
= \frac 1 9 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{ (2n+1)^2} 
= \frac 1 9 G$$

Hence,

$$\AA + \BB = G + \frac 1 9 G = \frac{10}{9} G$$

as desired.

Comment: right, same way, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, with
$ \frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2+t^4}= \frac{1}{1+t^2} +\frac{3t^2}{1+t^6}$

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t^2)\ln t}{1-t^2+t^4}dt
=\int_0^1 \underset{=-G}{\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}}dt
+ \int_0^1 \underset{=-\frac13G}{\frac{3t^2\ln t}{1+t^6} \ \overset{t^3\to t}{dt}}=-\frac43G
\end{align}

Comment: Nice and so simple .....(after reading the solution)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - thanks

Comment: @Quanto-Elegant!

Answer (score 1):

You can arrive to the desired result starting at
$$I=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left( \frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}+\frac{2}{(6n+3)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^2}  \right)$$
Using the Hurwitz zeta function
$$S_a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^n}{(6n+a)^2}=\frac{1}{144} \left(\zeta \left(2,\frac{a}{12}\right)-\zeta  \left(2,\frac{a+6}{12}\right)\right)$$
$$S_1+2S_3+S_5=S_1+\frac{2}{9}C+S_5=$$ $$\frac{2}{9}C+\frac{1}{144}\left(\zeta \left(2,\frac{1}{12}\right)+\zeta \left(2,\frac{5}{12}\right)-\zeta
   \left(2,\frac{7}{12}\right)-\zeta \left(2,\frac{11}{12}\right)\right)$$ and use
$$\zeta \left(2,\frac{1}{12}\right)+\zeta \left(2,\frac{5}{12}\right)-\zeta
   \left(2,\frac{7}{12}\right)-\zeta \left(2,\frac{11}{12}\right)=160 C$$  You could do the same using the first derivative of the digamma function.

**Edit**

We could do the same without series expansion writing
$$\frac{(1+t^2)}{1-t^2+t^4}=\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac{a+1}{t^2-a}-\frac{b+1}{t^2-b} \right)$$ with $a=\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $b=\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and use, for a complex $c$,
$$J(c)=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(t)}{t^2-c}\,dt=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{c}}\left(4
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)\right)$$